# How 3rd party apps like pictaram do not hit instagram API limits?

Tags: instagram, access-token, instagram-api, rate-limiting

Instagram has default API limits for API calls, for sandbox users its 500 and live users its 5000 / hour for an access-token.

Like pictaram.com and picbear.com and other apps, which don't sign in users for getting access token from Instagram, provides services that you can pull data unlimited, for example, in pictaram I search for a hashtag media, normally if we assume that site has own access token which has 5000 calls for an hour can provide 100k images(because one call for tags recent media responses  with 20 pictures and next page URL) so you can get max 100k images with 1 access token if you use it for just a tag search but I could manage to get more than 100k media for a tag and the site continued to work like a charm.

How can these sites provides all data without hitting the API limits? They are acting just like Instagram itself.